# Can I use a different cassette on a SRAM Eagle NX bike for indoor training?

Tags: chain, cassette, parts, sram, trainer

I want to use a bike fitted with SRAM Eagle NX groupset on an indoor trainer, and to have a complete wheel including cassette for use on the trainer.

Would it make sense to use another 11 or 12-speed cassette instead of the current PG-1230 cassette ? Is it possible that it won't be as compatible with the chain, and make the ride less smooth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you'll need to match the same cog count to your shifter. In other words, an 11-spd shifter necessitates an 11-spd cog. You don't need to match the level (e.g., NX vs X01). You probably want to stick with the same brand for optimal shifting, but that's a lower priority.

Comment: Why would you even need to shift at all on an indoor trainer?

Comment: @leftaroundabout on a "dumb" trainer: to get different resistance level. on a "smart" trainer to cope with a hill in your virtual world